# Dependency injection in Haskell: solving the task idiomatically

Tags: haskell

What is the idiomatic Haskell solution for dependency injection?

E.g., suppose you have an interface `frobby`, and you needed to pass an instance conforming to `frobby` around (there might be multiple varieties of these instances, say, `foo`, and `bar`).

Typical operations would be:

- functions that take some value `X` and return some value `Y`. E.g., this might be a database accessor, taking a SQL query & a connector and returning a dataset. You might need to implement postgres, mysql, and a mock test system.
- functions that take some value `Z` and return a closure relating to `Z`, specialized to a given `foo` or `bar` style, chosen at runtime.

One person solved the problem as follows:

http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2011/05/dependency-injection-haskell-style.html

But I don't know if that's the canonical way to manage this task.

Comment: Could you clarify more what operations you need to support? And in Haskell language -- e.g. by `instance` you mean values, and by interface you mean `typeclass`? Because typically this kind of thing would be done via existentials, and a Reader monad (in my experience).

Comment: @DonStewart: I'm using the usual OO nomenclature for instance/interface. I'll add comments on operations in the question.

Comment: I don't think there's a single canonical solution, rather it seems that developers will use whichever of several approaches best fits the project requirements.  That said, I would consider the linked blogpage to be one of the better possible solutions.

Comment: This is relevant to my interests...

Answer (score 137, accepted):

I think the proper answer here is, and I will probably receive a few downvotes just for saying this:  forget the term *dependency injection*.  Just forget it.  It's a trendy buzzword from the OO world, but nothing more.

Let's solve the real problem.  Keep in mind that you are solving a problem, and that problem is the particular programming task at hand.  Don't make your problem "implementing dependency injection".

We'll take the example of a logger, because that's a basic piece of functionality many programs will want to have, and there are lots of different types of loggers:  One that logs to stderr, one that logs to a file, a database, and one that simply does nothing.  To unify all them you want a type:

```
type Logger m = String -> m ()
```

You could also choose a fancier type to save some keystrokes:

```
class PrettyPrint a where
    pretty :: a -> String

type Logger m = forall a. (PrettyPrint a) => a -> m ()
```

Now let's define a few loggers using the latter variant:

```
noLogger :: (Monad m) => Logger m
noLogger _ = return ()

stderrLogger :: (MonadIO m) => Logger m
stderrLogger x = liftIO . hPutStrLn stderr $ pretty x

fileLogger :: (MonadIO m) => FilePath -> Logger m
fileLogger logF x =
    liftIO . withFile logF AppendMode $ \h ->
        hPutStrLn h (pretty x)

acidLogger :: (MonadIO m) => AcidState MyDB -> Logger m
acidLogger db x = update' db . AddLogLine $ pretty x
```

You can see how this builds a graph of dependencies.  The `acidLogger` depends on a database connection for the `MyDB` database layout.  Passing arguments to functions is about the most natural way to express dependencies in a program.  After all a function is just a value that depends on another value.  That is also true for actions.  If your action depends on a logger, then naturally it is a function of loggers:

```
printFile :: (MonadIO m) => Logger m -> FilePath -> m ()
printFile log fp = do
    log ("Printing file: " ++ fp)
    liftIO (readFile fp >>= putStr)
    log "Done printing."
```

See how easy this is?  At some point this makes you realize how much easier your life will be, when you just forget all the nonsense that OO has taught you.

Comment: You will also receive a few more upvotes for saying this...

Comment: Understand that I use "DI" as a shorthand for a particularly handy concept that I don't know how to reference without a lot of words otherwise. You frame it as, afaict with my weak knowledge of Haskell, a particular type alias, and leverage that type inference to ensure that the calling function hits the correct function.  It's not particularly magical, of course (nor is the OO variant).  I want(ed) to grasp a wholly non-OO solution to the particular problem.

Comment: i'm an OO purist and i LUV this. brilliant!

Comment: @Paul: My point is that you need to understand what exactly the OO solution solves in order to solve it in a non-OO way.  In this case you will find that `ReaderT` is very close to what DI does.  And that's just functions and function application, where in some spots the application is hidden.  In other words, in most cases OO just invents new terms for known and old bad ideas, and just because of the terms people seem to be overly excited even when the underlying concept is actually a *very* bad idea, like singleton classes (global mutable variables in disguise).  It's better to forget OO.

Comment: If you have a lot of dependencies, you might want to wrap them in something like a State or Reader monad. You can also nest monads.

Comment: @ertes, I have upvoted not only for the whole post(which also very good) but mainly for the first two lines of your post.

Comment: Do not get it, you didn't explain most important part which is where log should be sent to printFile, because this kind of glue code is a reason to have DI.

Comment: +1 to @panurg. this misses the essential element of DI, which is actually injecting the dependencies automatically, not merely allowing for the insertion of dependencies, which in and of itself is necessary, but not sufficient. the author's flippant remark about OO at the end would be more incisive if the post itself did not betray a lack of understanding of why OO communities like DI.

Comment: @tabdulla I agree, this post doesn't solve the problem at all.

Comment: We've been heavily invested in Scala using the Play! Framework and while going through the changelogs in Play! I came across https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection. It makes me doubt our investment in the framework. We're sticking to the version that don't have DI at all.

Comment: @panurg @tabdulla. This issue does solve DI. "Sending" the log to `printFile` is just passing the logger as a param. If you want to use `FileLogger`, just call `printFile fileLogger filePath`. The `acidLogger` is a good example for "DB injection". You could partially apply it so that `myAcidLogger x = acidLogger MySql x` (this is similar to modules in DI frameworks, which create specific implementations to interfaces). Then you just use `myAcidLogger` and you have MySql "injected" for free. You can also swap `MySql` for something else, without afecting its usages.

Comment: Provided solution looks good for Haskell or other functional programming languages. However, it is rarely the best in OOP. It looks more like poor man's DI which becomes increasingly tedious with complexity. There is a reason there are automated tools for constructing object graphs (IOC container). mentionig OO in a negative context was not a good idea. You see, OO has some good points, which when used properly, lead to great solutions. Even singleton has its valid use. What do you think  an in-memory cache is? My point is, Not everything fits neatly into the functional way of doing things.

Comment: @Vakhtang OOP doesn't provide strong enough ergonomic or safety guarantees around parametricity for this to be tenable, yes. This would be a terrible idea in OO, but then again, using metaprogramming to dynamically inject dependencies at runtime would be a catastrophically bad idea in Haskell.

Comment: In OO world you would define a Logger interface with as many methods/functions you want. The solution you propose works only for single method interfaces. How do I define a set of methods under the same interface/type?

Comment: @Kakaji Just stick the set of methods in a datastructure (can be just a tuple, or something with names).  Or provide multiple arguments to your functions.  Or you can use a typeclass.

Comment: @tabdulla the whole point of dependency injection is to force the programmer to think in terms of dependencies, factory methods and constructors. the automatic "injection" is just a topological sort through the dependency graph, it's just there when you formulate everything like that.

Answer (score 15):

Use `pipes`.  I won't say it is idiomatic because the library is still relatively new, but I think it exactly solves your problem.

For example, let's say that you want to wrap an interface to some database:

```
import Control.Proxy

-- This is just some pseudo-code.  I'm being lazy here
type QueryString = String
type Result = String
query :: QueryString -> IO Result

database :: (Proxy p) => QueryString -> Server p QueryString Result IO r
database = runIdentityK $ foreverK $ \queryString -> do
    result <- lift $ query queryString
    respond result
```

We can then model one interface to the database:

```
user :: (Proxy p) => () -> Client p QueryString Result IO r
user () = forever $ do
    lift $ putStrLn "Enter a query"
    queryString <- lift getLine
    result <- request queryString
    lift $ putStrLn $ "Result: " ++ result
```

You connect them like so:

```
runProxy $ database >-> user
```

This will then allow the user to interact with the database from the prompt.

We can then switch out the database with a mock database:

```
mockDatabase :: (Proxy p) => QueryString -> Server p QueryString Result IO r
mockDatabase = runIdentityK $ foreverK $ \query -> respond "42"
```

Now we can switch out the database for the mock one very easily:

```
runProxy $ mockDatabase >-> user
```

Or we can switch out the database client.  For example, if we noticed a particular client session triggered some weird bug, we could reproduce it like so:

```
reproduce :: (Proxy p) => () -> Client p QueryString Result IO ()
reproduce () = do
    request "SELECT * FROM WHATEVER"
    request "CREATE TABLE BUGGED"
    request "I DON'T REALLY KNOW SQL"
```

... then hook it up like so:

```
runProxy $ database >-> reproduce
```

`pipes` lets you split out streaming or interactive behaviors into modular components so you can mix and match them however you please, which is the essence of dependency injection.

To learn more about `pipes`, just read the tutorial at [Control.Proxy.Tutorial](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pipes/3.0.0/doc/html/Control-Proxy-Tutorial.html).

Comment: Wow, I haven't consider this use of `pipes`. I thought it was "just" for streaming, but it is quite nice to see that it opens up other possibilities :)

Comment: How would this example expand to injecting multiple dependencies?

Answer (score 5):

To build on ertes's answer, I think the desired signature for `printFile` is `printFile :: (MonadIO m, MonadLogger m) => FilePath -> m ()`, which I read as "I will print the given file. To do so, I need to do some IO and some logging."

I am no expert, but here's my attempt at this solution. I will be grateful for comments and suggestions on how to improve this.

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

module DependencyInjection where

import Prelude hiding (log)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Control.Monad.Identity
import System.IO
import Control.Monad.State

-- |Any function that can turn a string into an action is considered a Logger.
type Logger m = String -> m ()

-- |Logger that does nothing, for testing.
noLogger :: (Monad m) => Logger m
noLogger _ = return ()

-- |Logger that prints to STDERR.
stderrLogger :: (MonadIO m) => Logger m
stderrLogger x = liftIO $ hPutStrLn stderr x

-- |Logger that appends messages to a given file.
fileLogger :: (MonadIO m) => FilePath -> Logger m
fileLogger filePath value = liftIO logToFile
  where
      logToFile :: IO ()
      logToFile = withFile filePath AppendMode $ flip hPutStrLn value


-- |Programs have to provide a way to the get the logger to use.
class (Monad m) => MonadLogger m where
    getLogger :: m (Logger m)

-- |Logs a given string using the logger obtained from the environment.
log :: (MonadLogger m) => String -> m ()
log value = do logger <- getLogger
               logger value

-- |Example function that we want to run in different contexts, like
--  skip logging during testing.
printFile :: (MonadIO m, MonadLogger m) => FilePath -> m ()
printFile fp = do
    log ("Printing file: " ++ fp)
    liftIO (readFile fp >>= putStr)
    log "Done printing."


-- |Let's say this is the real program: it keeps the log file name using StateT.
type RealProgram = StateT String IO

-- |To get the logger, build the right fileLogger.
instance MonadLogger RealProgram where
    getLogger = do filePath <- get
                   return $ fileLogger filePath

-- |And this is how you run printFile "for real".
realMain :: IO ()
realMain = evalStateT (printFile "file-to-print.txt") "log.out"


-- |This is a fake program for testing: it will not do any logging.
type FakeProgramForTesting = IO

-- |Use noLogger.
instance MonadLogger FakeProgramForTesting where
    getLogger = return noLogger

-- |The program doesn't do any logging, but still does IO.
fakeMain :: IO ()
fakeMain = printFile "file-to-print.txt"
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use [existentially quantified data types](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Existential_type). Let's take [XMonad](http://xmonad.org/) as an example. There is an (`frobby`) interface for layouts – [`LayoutClass`](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad/XMonad-Core.html#t%3aLayoutClass) typeclass:

```
-- | Every layout must be an instance of 'LayoutClass', which defines
-- the basic layout operations along with a sensible default for each.
-- 
-- ...
-- 
class Show (layout a) => LayoutClass layout a where

    ...
```

and existential data type [Layout](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad/XMonad-Core.html#t%3aLayout):

```
-- | An existential type that can hold any object that is in 'Read'
--   and 'LayoutClass'.
data Layout a = forall l. (LayoutClass l a, Read (l a)) => Layout (l a)
```

that can wrap any (`foo` or `bar`) instance of `LayoutClass` interface. It is itself a layout:

```
instance LayoutClass Layout Window where
    runLayout (Workspace i (Layout l) ms) r = fmap (fmap Layout) `fmap` runLayout (Workspace i l ms) r
    doLayout (Layout l) r s  = fmap (fmap Layout) `fmap` doLayout l r s
    emptyLayout (Layout l) r = fmap (fmap Layout) `fmap` emptyLayout l r
    handleMessage (Layout l) = fmap (fmap Layout) . handleMessage l
    description (Layout l)   = description l
```

Now it is possible to use `Layout` data type generically with only `LayoutClass` interface methods. Appropriate layout which implements `LayoutClass` interface will be selected at run-time, there is a bunch of them in [XMonad.Layout](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad/XMonad-Layout.html) and in [xmonad-contrib](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/). And, of course, it is possible to switch between different layouts dynamically:

```
-- | Set the layout of the currently viewed workspace
setLayout :: Layout Window -> X ()
setLayout l = do
    ss@(W.StackSet { W.current = c@(W.Screen { W.workspace = ws })}) <- gets windowset
    handleMessage (W.layout ws) (SomeMessage ReleaseResources)
    windows $ const $ ss {W.current = c { W.workspace = ws { W.layout = l } } }
```

Comment: I gather that some people consider this an anti-pattern; they contend it's better to just have a `Layout` ADT who's fields are all function types...

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid I dunno :) This is just what I saw.

Comment: Sure. It's not a criticism, just a note. :-)

Comment: This is not an instance of the antipattern. The existential antipattern applies only to very simple, albeit popular, cases.