# How to swap functions (e.g.for tests) in pure functional programming

Tags: dependency-injection, functional-programming

I'm trying to understand what is an FP-alternative to good old dependency injection from OOP.
Say I have the following app (pseudocode)

`app()` is where application starts. It allows user to register and list user posts (whatever). These two functions are composed out of several other functions (register does it step by step, imperatively, while list posts really composes them (at least this is how I understand function composition).

```
app()

  registerUser(u)
    validate(u)
    persist(u)
      callSaveToDB(u)
    notify(u)
      sendsEmail

  listPosts(u)
    postsToView(loadUserPosts(findUser(u)))
```

Now I'd like to test this stuff (`registerUser` and `listPosts`) and would like to have stubbed functions so that I don't call db etc - you know, usual testing stuff.
I know it's possible to pass functions to functions e.g

```
registerUser(validateFn, persistFn, notifyFn, u)
```

and have it partially applied so it looks like `registerUser(u)` with other functions closed over and so on. But it all needs to be done on app boot level as it was in OOP (wiring dependencies and bootstraping an app). It looks like manually doing this will take ages and tons of boilerplate code. Is there something obvious I'm missing there? Is there any other way of doing that?

EDIT:

I see having IO there is not a good example. So what if I have function composed of several other functions and one of them is really heavy (in terms of computations) and I'd like to swap it?

Simply - I'm looking for FP way of doing DI stuff.

Comment: Ok, but I guess doesn't matter in this case. What if I want to compose function logic out of several other building blocks (they may not do any IO)?

Comment: Also I need to eventually call db at some point, so this has to be handled somewhere

Comment: Still, it doesn't answer my question in any way (or I'm just missing your point entirely)

Comment: DI is not a programming language concept, it is a tooling concept. Which basically means there is some sort of compiler plugin or other tools separate from language specification that are used to do DI. So FP - a programming paradigm - can't have DI although some specific FP language tooling may support DI in their own ways

Comment: @Ankur Disagree -- Dependency Injection is a design pattern, it doesn't need a tool or plugin to be leveraged.

Comment: dup of http://stackoverflow.com/a/14329487/83805

Answer (score 1):

The way to answer this is to drop the phrase "dependency injection" and think about it more fundamentally. Write down interfaces as types for each component. Implement functions that have those types. Replace them as needed. There's no magic, and language features like type classes make it easy for the compiler to ensure you can substitute methods in an interface.

The previous Haskell-specific answer, shows how to use Haskell types for the API: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14329487/83805