# In Haskell is dependency injection using ExistentialQuantification an anti-pattern?

Tags: haskell, dependency-injection

I am a Haskell newbie, and I am thinking about how I can modularize my [Rest](http://silkapp.github.io/rest/) application, which essentially passes around a ReaderT everywhere. I have devised a primitive working example of how to do that (below) using ExistentialQuantification. In a comment to a [relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14343138/375570), user MathematicalOrchid claimed something similar to be an anti-pattern. Is *this* an anti-pattern? In newbie terms, can you explain why if so and show a better alternative?

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Data.List (intersect)

data Config = Config Int Bool


data User = Jane | John | Robot deriving (Show)
listUsers = [Jane, John, Robot]

class Database d where
  search :: d -> String -> IO [User]
  fetch  :: d -> Int -> IO (Maybe User)


data LiveDb = LiveDb
instance Database LiveDb where
  search d q   = return $ filter ((q==) . intersect q . show) listUsers
  fetch d i = return $ if i<3  then Just $ listUsers!!i else Nothing

data TestDb = TestDb
instance Database TestDb where
  search _ _ = return [Robot]
  fetch _ _ = return $ Just Robot

data Context = forall d. (Database d) => Context {
    db :: d
  , config :: Config
  }

liveContext = Context { db = LiveDb, config = Config 123 True }
testContext = Context { db = TestDb, config = Config 123 True }

runApi :: String -> ReaderT Context IO String
runApi query = do  
  Context { db = db } <- ask
  liftIO . fmap show $ search db query

main = do
  let q = "Jn"

  putStrLn $ "searching users for " ++ q

  liveResult <- runReaderT (runApi q) liveContext
  putStrLn $ "live result " ++ liveResult

  testResult <- runReaderT (runApi q) testContext
  putStrLn $ "test result " ++ testResult
```

#### Edit: a working example based on the accepted answer

```hs
import Control.Monad.Reader
import Control.Monad.Trans
import Data.List (intersect)

data Config = Config Int Bool


data User = Jane | John | Robot deriving (Show)
listUsers = [Jane, John, Robot]

data Database = Database {
    search :: String -> IO [User]
  , fetch  :: Int -> IO (Maybe User)
  }


liveDb :: Database
liveDb = Database search fetch where
  search q = return $ filter ((q==) . intersect q . show) listUsers
  fetch i = return $ if i<3  then Just $ listUsers!!i else Nothing

testDb :: Database
testDb = Database search fetch where
  search _ = return [Robot]
  fetch  _ = return $ Just Robot

data Context = Context {
    db :: Database
  , config :: Config
  }

liveContext = Context { db = liveDb, config = Config 123 True }
testContext = Context { db = testDb, config = Config 123 True }

runApi :: String -> ReaderT Context IO String
runApi query = do  
  d <- fmap db $ ask
  liftIO . fmap show $ search d $ query

main = do
  let q = "Jn"

  putStrLn $ "searching users for " ++ q

  liveResult <- runReaderT (runApi q) liveContext
  putStrLn $ "live result " ++ liveResult

  testResult <- runReaderT (runApi q) testContext
  putStrLn $ "test result " ++ testResult
```

Comment: Obligatory reference: the canonical denunciation, [Haskell Antipattern: Existential Typeclass](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you pattern-match on a `Context`, you get in the `db` field a value of a type that you can never know precisely; all you're allowed to know about it is that it's a `Database` instance, and thus you can use that class' methods with it.  But that means that, from the point of view of the `Context` type, the existential `d` type affords it no more capabilities than this type does:

```
-- The "record of methods" pattern
data Database =
  Database { search :: String -> IO [User]
           , fetch  :: Int -> IO (Maybe User)
           }

liveDb :: Database
liveDb = Database search fetch
  where search d q = return $ filter ((q==) . intersect q . show) listUsers
        fetch  d i = return $ if i<3  then Just $ listUsers!!i else Nothing

testDb :: Database
testDb = Database search fetch
  where search _ _ = return [Robot]
        fetch  _ _ = return (Just Robot)

data Context =
  Context { db     :: Database
          , config :: Config
          }
```

That's the core argument against using existential types in the manner that you've done—there is a completely equivalent alternative that doesn't require existential types.

Comment: Wow, that's very elegant, thank you. The `database` parameter for liveDb and testDb seems out of place though.

Comment: Something wrong with the types here. `liveDb` and `testDb` have type `a -> Database` not just `Database`...

Answer (score 10):

The argument against existential types is quite simple (and strong): often, you can avoid both the existential type *and* type class machinery, and use plain functions instead.

This is clearly the case where your class has the form

```
class D a where
   method1 :: a -> T1
   method2 :: a -> T2
   -- ...
```

as in the posted `Database` example, since its instances can be replaced by values in a plain record type

```
data D = D {
   method1 :: T1
,  method2 :: T2
   -- ...
}
```

This is, essentially, the solution by @LuisCasillas .

However, note that the above translation relies on types `T1,T2` not to depend on `a`. What if this is not the case? E.g. what if we had

```
class Database d where
  search :: d -> String -> [User]
  fetch  :: d -> Int -> Maybe User
  insert :: d -> User -> d
```

The above is a "pure" (no-IO) interface to a database, also allowing updates through `insert`. An instance could then be

```
data LiveDb = LiveDb [User]
instance Database LiveDb where
   search (LiveDb d) q = filter ((q==) . intersect q . show) d
   fetch  (LiveDb d) i = case drop i d of [] -> Nothing ; (x:_) -> Just x
   insert (LiveDb d) u = LiveDb (u:d)
```

Note that here we do use the parameter `d`, unlike in the original case where it was a placeholder.

Can we do without classes and existentials here?

```
data Database =
  Database { search :: String -> [User]
           , fetch  :: Int -> Maybe User
           , insert :: User -> Database
           }
```

Notice that above we are returning an abstract `Database` in `insert`. This interface is more general than the existential-classy one, since it allows `insert` to change the underlying representation for the database. I.e., `insert` could move from a list-based representation to a tree-based one. This is like having `insert` acting from the existentially-quantified `Database` to itself, instead of from a concrete instance to itself.

Anyway, let's write `LiveDb` in the record-style way:

```
liveDb :: Database
liveDb = Database (search' listUsers) (fetch' listUsers) (insert' listUsers)
  where search' d q = filter ((q==) . intersect q . show) d
        fetch' d i  = case drop i d of [] -> Nothing ; (x:_) -> Just x
        insert' d u = Database (search' d') (fetch' d') (insert' d')
              where d' = u:d
        listUsers = [Jane, John, Robot]
```

Above I had to pass the underlying state `d` to each function, and in `insert` I had to update such state.

Overall, I find the above more involved than the `instance Database LiveDb` methods, which require no state-passing. Surely, we can apply a little refactoring and clarify the code:

```
makeLiveDb :: [User] -> Database
makeLiveDb d = Database search fetch insert
   where search q = filter ((q==) . intersect q . show) d
         fetch i  = case drop i d of [] -> Nothing ; (x:_) -> Just x
         insert u = makeLiveDb (u:d)

liveDb :: Database
liveDb = makeLiveDb [Jane, John, Robot]
```

This is a bit better, yet not as simple than the plain instance. There is no straightforward winner in this case, and which style to use is a matter of personal preference.

Personally, I stay away from existentially-quantified classes as much as possible, since in many, many cases they lose to much simpler approaches. However, I'm not dogmatic about them, and allow myself to use the "anti-pattern" when the alternative starts becoming too clumsy.

---

As an alternative, one could use an external function working at the abstract level, only:

```
data Database =
  Database { search :: String -> [User]
           -- let's neglect other methods for simplicity's sake
           }

insert :: Database -> User -> Database
insert (Database s) u = Database s'
   where s' str = s str ++ [ u | show u == str ] -- or something similar
```

The advantage of doing this is that `insert` works on the abstract `Database`, whatever its underlying data structure is. The disadvantage is that, in this way, `insert` can only access the database through its "methods", and can only work by building closures upon closures. If we also implemented a `remove` method, applying `insert` and `delete` many times will cause a larger and larger memory footprint, since `remove` can not remove the element from the underlying data structure, but can only build yet another closure which skips over the removed element. More pragmatically, it would be as if `insert` and `remove` simply appended to a log, and `search` scanned the log to see if the most recent action on an element was an insertion or a removal. This will not have a great performance.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up another reason "This interface is more general than the existential-classy one, since it allows insert to change the underlying representation". But I'm unclear about "Overall, I find the above more involved than the instance Database LiveDb methods, which require no state-passing" I only see `Database search fetch insert where` that makes it a little more complicated. Is that what you mean? I'm a little confused about the state-passing comment. Couldn't you rewrite your example so that `Database` functions start with `Database ->` to make it the same as in the instance?

Comment: My point is that `insert` is a bit more complex than in the instance: instead of just changing the old list into a new list, it has to re-construct a whole database value out of that. Further, adding a `Database ->` argument will _not_ work without a major overhaul. This is because if you take a `Database`, you no longer have access to the underlying list data structure (it could be a tree, or anything else), so you are left with using a `Database` through its interface, only! This may also lead to less efficient code.

Comment: @BijouTrouvaille I updated my answer to clarify this last point. Alas, there are so many possibilities that it is impossible to analyze all the "what if..." scenarios.

Comment: "you no longer have access to the underlying list data structure" that's what I didn't realize at first. Thanks @chi, all this makes much more sense now.